# Reshaping arrays in an array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of 40 arrays, each with a 1x150 shape. Is there a way to reshape the arrays so that I have 40 arrays of 3x50 arrays?

I am not sure if there is a way to use np.reshape and just do it in one line, is there?

Comment: "I have an array of 40 arrays..."  Is it actually a 3D array with shape (40, 1, 150), or is it a 1D array with dtype "object" (with the objects being arrays with shape (1, 150))?

Comment: It is the later, a 1D array with `dtype=object`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this really an `array` of np.arrays, or a list of those arrays?  If it is an array, what is its shape and dtype?

If it is a list, or array with `dtype=object`, then you have to iterate over items, and reshape each one.

```
 [a.reshape(3,50) for a in A]
```

If you have a 3d array, its shape may be `(40, 1, 150)`.

```
 A.reshape(40, 3, 50)
```

---

Since the items in an 'object' array could be anything - strings, arrays, lists, dict - there can't be a `reshape` that applies to all of them 'at once'.  Even if they are all arrays, they could each have different dimensions.  In fact that is usually how an array of arrays is produced.

```
In [5]: np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3]])
Out[5]: array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3]], dtype=object)
```

You have to take special steps to construct an object array with items that all have the same shape.  `np.array` tries to construct the highest dimensional array it can.

```
In [7]: A=np.empty((2,),dtype=object)
In [8]: A[0] = np.array([1,2,3])
In [9]: A[1] = np.array([4,5,6])
In [10]: A
Out[10]: array([array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

Another way to look at it: `reshape` just changes an attribute of the array.  It does nothing to the data.  In the case of a 3d array, there is one `shape` value, and one block of data.

But in the array of objects, each object has its own `shape` and `data`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is an array with `dtype=object` and I know I could iterate over them. I should've probably been more clear in clarifying what I mean by "one line". I was curious in knowing if a version of `reshape` function exists that would do this.

Comment: I added some notes on the `dtype=object` case.

Answer (score 5):

For reshaping a numpy-array containing numpy-arrays I found [this contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032948/flatten-numpy-array-with-sub-arrays-of-different-dimensions) helpful - you can first use `b=np.hstack(array_of_arrays)` to create a flattened 1D numpy-array, and then just reshape `b`.