# Flatten numpy array with sub-arrays of different dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This seems like a simple enough task, but I haven't found how to do it using `numpy`. Consider the example array:

```
import numpy as np
aa = np.array([np.array([13.16]), np.array([1.58 , 1.2]), np.array([13.1]), np.array([1. , 2.6])], dtype=object)
```

I need a general way to flatten that array into a single array of `N` elements, with `N=every float in all the sub-arrays`. In this case it would be:

```
aa = np.array([13.16, 1.58 , 1.2, 13.1, 1. , 2.6])
```

I've tried `np.ndarray.flatten()` (tried all the 'order'  options)) but I get back the same unchanged `aa` array.

Why is `np.ndarray.flatten()` not working and how can I accomplish this?

The solution should be as general as possible since the example `aa` array I'm using here will actually be filled with sub-arrays of different lengths in my real code.

Comment: `aa` is already 1d. `flatten` only changes the `shape`. It doesn't operate across this object dtype barrier. `concatenate` treats the array as a list of arrays; that's a very different operation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)

```
>>> np.hstack(aa)
array([13.16,  1.58,  1.2 , 13.1 ,  1.  ,  2.6 ])
```

Comment: Thank you Cory. Any idea why `np.ndarray.flatten()` does not work? Does it only work on arrays where all the sub-arrays have equal dimension? That's not stated in the docs.

Comment: @Gabriel `np.ndarray.flatten()` is working.  `flatten` returns a single-dimensional array from an ndarray.  `aa.ndim` already is 1, so there is nothing for flatten to change.  `aa` has data type object, so numpy doesn't know and doesn't care that it happens to contain arrays.  What you want to do is tell numpy to treat each element of `aa` as an array and join them together in a new array of data type float, which is what this answer does.

Answer (score 1):

If all sub-arrays are 1D, you can also use `np.concatenate` to save a bit of time. As far as I understand `np.hstack` is a wrapper of `np.concatenate` that reduces to the same operation if the input is 1D.

```
np.concatenate(aa)
# array([13.16,  1.58,  1.2 , 13.1 ,  1.  ,  2.6 ])

np.allclose(np.concatenate(aa), np.hstack(aa))
# True
```

```
%timeit np.hstack(aa)
5.53 µs ± 28.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit np.concatenate(aa)
2.2 µs ± 46.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```