# Can a numpy array have elements that are numpy arrays themselves?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am not very familiar with python so I apologise in advance. Is it at all possible to have a numpy array such as `numpy.array([a, b, c])` and add that array to an empty numpy array as an element?

Assuming this is possible, is it possible to then sum the first value of each element of multiple arrays within the main numpy array. For instance,

`numpy.array([numpy.array([a,b,c]), numpy.array([d,e,f])])`

to then become

`numpy.array([a + d, b + e, c + f])`

I hope I have managed to explain clearly if unsure please feel free to ask me to expand.

Many Thanks :-)

Comment: Fire up your python interpreter and try it out.

Comment: There is an `object` `dtype` that allows arrays to contain 'anything', much as lists do.  But creating such an array can be tricky.  `np.array` tries, if possible, to create a multidimensional array of numbers.  If falls back on the object dtype if it can't - or it raises an error.  We get lots of SO questions from people who don't understand these complexities, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032948/flatten-numpy-array-with-sub-arrays-of-different-dimensions

Comment: read numpy tutorials. nd array refers to n-dimensional arrays. 3D array could include multiple 2D arrays etc.

Comment: Do you really need arrays within an array?  How about a 2d array instead?  `np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])`. Or just adding 2 arrays together?  np.array([1,2,3])+np.array([4,5,6])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 1d arrays:

```
In [79]: x1=np.array([1,2,3])
In [80]: x2=np.array([4,5,6])
```

Make new array - 2d, with 2 rows

```
In [81]: x12 = np.array((x1,x2))
In [82]: x12
Out[82]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

`np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])` does the same thing.

The arrays can be summed, element by element:

```
In [83]: x1 + x2
Out[83]: array([5, 7, 9])
```

rows of the 2d array can also be summed:

```
In [84]: x12.sum(axis=0)
Out[84]: array([5, 7, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays of arrays are essentially what matrices are, so I'd just make an n-dimensional numpy array. That way you can sum element-wise in a given direction.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], np.int32) # 2x3 matrix
```

Normally you would want to loop through indices but for your example it makes more sense to do the summations individually :)

```
a_plus_d = sum(x[:,0]) # sum first column
b_plus_e = sum(x[:,1]) # sum second column
c_plus_f = sum(x[:,2]) # sum third column
```

Comment: Ah that makes complete sense! Life saver, thank you very much! :-)