# Problems in np.reshape arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy, reshape

I have a problem when [np.reshape](/questions/tagged/np.reshape) an array.
I have a **list** `roi_x` with a total size of 120 elements, each of which is a np.array of `float` of different sizes:

```
len(roi_x)
Out: 120
for i in range(len(roi_x)): 
    print(len(roi_x[i]))`
625
3125
6250
625
3125
6250
... # and so on
```

I want to reshape it, but I get an error (even though I get the reshaped array):

```
roi_x = np.reshape(roi_x, (20,6))

VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
```

After a bit of research, I adjusted my code as suggested and I don't get the error anymore and I am happy with the outcome:

```
roi_x = np.array(roi_x, dtype=object)   # I added dtype=object
roi_x.shape
Out: (120,)                             # I get just the first dimension
roi_x = np.reshape(roi_x, (20,6))
roi_x.shape
Out: (20, 6)
```

However, when I try to do the same with another array `roi_x` of different size:

```
len(roi_x)
Out: 192
for i in range(len(roi_x)): 
    print(len(roi_x[i]))`
625
625
625
625
625
625
... # in this case, all with the same size
```

And I try to reshape it following the same procedure (but with a different shape):

```
roi_x = np.array(roi_x, dtype=object)
roi_x.shape
Out: (192, 625)                    # it is already a different outcome compared to before, there is a 2nd dimension
roi_x = np.reshape(roi_x, (48,4))  # 48*4=192 so it should be ok
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 120000 into shape (48,4)
```

I can't figure out what I am doing different between my two examples.
Any ideas?

I had a look at this : [Reshaping arrays in an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900853/reshaping-arrays-in-an-array-of-arrays)

and I tried to reshape each item, but I get an error:

```
roi_x = [i.reshape(48, 4) for i in roi_x]

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 625 into shape (48,4)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Forget about the `reshape` for the moment, and focus on what `np.array(your_list)` does.  If the elements differ in shape, the result is a `ragged array` - that's still very much like the original list.  If they are all the same size, it makes a n-d array (with default numeric dtype).  This is the default behavior of `np.array`.  The "ragged" case is a backup one, used when it can't make a proper n-d numeric array.

Comment: `reshape` cannot change the total number of elements.

Comment: Your first example is a 1D array of 120 objects (that happen to be also arrays, of various size). So, you can reshape an array of 120 objects into a 2D-array of 20×6 objects. Your second example is not a 1D array of 192 objects (that would happen to be arrays of 625 numbers). It is directly a 2D-array of 192×625 numbers. Your can't reshape an array of 192×625 number into an array of 48×4 numbers.

Comment: Note that the second example is the normal one. `np.array` is supposed to be called with a 1D-list, or a 2D-list that is a list of lists of same size, or a 3D-list, that is list of lists of lists of same size at all level, etc. The 1st example is the deprecated behavior (and frankly, that is a normal and useful deprecation: the whole point of numpy is void for such arrays. If you really need such array, keep them as python lists rather).

Comment: But well, the behavior difference all come from the fact that np.array does not behave similarly for "evenly shaped" lists than for heterogenous ones. So `np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]` is a 2D-array. `np.array([[1,2],[3]]`) is not.

Comment: You could reshape to `(48,4,625)`.  `[i.reshape(25,25) for i in roi_x]` should work.  Or reshape the whole thing to (48,4,25,25).